# Django Insert Data file location

Tags: python, sql, django

In Django, I want to insert a lot of  data into models that I created like the following code.

```
for x in range(1,100)
    a = person(name ="Smith,Joe", age=25, city="New York)
    a.save()
```

Where is the file structure should I put this code so that I can insert the data?

Comment: [`inital_data.yaml/json/xml`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)? You'll have to copy-paste it 100 times though, but it's "the right way" of providing initial set of data.

Comment: @JOHN thanks for the fast reply. Should I put that in a python file?

Comment: Read the documentation, it's quite well-explained. (hint: `initial_data` in my previous comment is a link)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few apps you can use to generate dummy fixtures for testing purposes:

- [django-dilla](http://aerosol.github.io/django-dilla/)
- [django-autofixture](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture)
- [django-fixture-generator](https://github.com/alex/django-fixture-generator)
- [django-dynamic-fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture)